# Рow to parse and take unique values php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array consisting of two arrays with keys.
How it is possible to exclude identical keys and form one array?
But I can't assign a variable to my arrays to merge them.
The number of such arrays can be up to 10 pieces and each time the result is different.
My task is to parse and, as a result, produce one array with unacceptable keys. But I can't handle it

```
                   $dataResult = [{"predictors":[{"descr":"C","min":0.05,"max":0.1,"field":"c"},{"descr":"Si","min":0.01,"max":0.12,"field":"si"},{"descr":"Mn","min":0.22,"max":1.43,"field":"mn"},{"descr":"S","min":0.001,"max":0.0123,"field":"s"},{"descr":"P","min":0.0046,"max":0.015,"field":"p"},{"descr":"Cr","min":0.01,"max":0.5946,"field":"cr"},{"descr":"Ni","min":0.0086,"max":0.05,"field":"ni"},{"descr":"Cu","min":0.0162,"max":0.07,"field":"cu"},{"descr":"N","min":0.0035,"max":0.0084,"field":"n"},{"descr":"Al","min":0.0302,"max":0.0604,"field":"al"},{"descr":"Ti","min":0,"max":0.0348,"field":"ti"},{"descr":"B","min":0,"max":0.0005,"field":"b"},{"descr":"Mo","min":0,"max":0.0125,"field":"mo"},{"descr":"V","min":0,"max":0.0139,"field":"v"},{"descr":"Nb","min":0.0017,"max":0.085,"field":"nb"},{"descr":"T6","min":1019,"max":1105,"field":"t6"},{"descr":"T\u043a\u043f","min":832,"max":868,"field":"tkp"},{"descr":"T\u0441\u043c","min":547,"max":672,"field":"tsm"},{"descr":"h, \u043c\u043c","min":0.6,"max":2.5,"field":"h_mm"},{"descr":"P2","min":633,"max":813,"field":"p2"},{"descr":"P3","min":708,"max":815,"field":"p3"},{"descr":"P6","min":461,"max":680,"field":"p6"},{"descr":"\u0414\u0440\u0435\u0441","min":0.73,"max":1.651,"field":"dres"},{"descr":"V, \u043c\/\u043c\u0438\u043d","min":40,"max":151,"field":"v_min"}],"pipeline_id":5544,"namePipeline":"HSLA_GM_Neuro_Oleg_ver.1.1"},{"predictors":[{"descr":"C","min":0,"max":0.1,"field":"c"},{"descr":"Si","min":0,"max":0.12,"field":"si"},{"descr":"Mn","min":0,"max":1.43,"field":"mn"},{"descr":"S","min":0,"max":0.0123,"field":"s"},{"descr":"P","min":0,"max":0.015,"field":"p"},{"descr":"Cr","min":0,"max":0.5946,"field":"cr"},{"descr":"Ni","min":0,"max":0.05,"field":"ni"},{"descr":"Cu","min":0,"max":0.07,"field":"cu"},{"descr":"N","min":0,"max":0.0084,"field":"n"},{"descr":"Al","min":0,"max":0.0604,"field":"al"},{"descr":"Ti","min":0,"max":0.0348,"field":"ti"},{"descr":"B","min":0,"max":0.0005,"field":"b"},{"descr":"Mo","min":0,"max":0.0125,"field":"mo"},{"descr":"V","min":0,"max":0.0139,"field":"v"},{"descr":"Nb","min":0,"max":0.085,"field":"nb"},{"descr":"T6","min":1019,"max":1105,"field":"t6"},{"descr":"T\u043a\u043f","min":832,"max":868,"field":"tkp"},{"descr":"T\u0441\u043c","min":547,"max":672,"field":"tsm"},{"descr":"\u0422\u043e\u043b\u0449\u0438\u043d\u0430","min":0.6,"max":2.5,"field":"tolshchina"},{"descr":"P2","min":633,"max":813,"field":"p2"},{"descr":"P3","min":708,"max":815,"field":"p3"},{"descr":"P6","min":461,"max":680,"field":"p6"},{"descr":"\u0423\u0434\u043b\u0438\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0438 \u0434\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u043a\u0435","min":0.73,"max":1.651,"field":"udlinenie_pri_dressirovke"},{"descr":"\u0421\u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u044c \u043f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0441\u044b \u0432","min":40,"max":151,"field":"skorost_polosi_v"}],"pipeline_id":5501,"namePipeline":"hsla 20s 20r 20s"}]
                   $dataResult = $dataResult->map(function ($i,$k){
                      $res = [];
                      foreach ($i['predictors'] as $k=>$v){
                        $res[$k] = $v['field'];
                      }

                      return $res;
                   });
```

Comment: Pretty unclear what you want. You should add what the expected output/result is supposed to be here, based on the example input data you have shown.

Comment: I want to get one array with unique values ​​of all those that are involved in the loop.
I have an array of several, depending on the number of iterations in the loop

Comment: `array_unique` exists.

Comment: array_unique can't help me, i need to check between all iterations for uniqueness

Comment: Okay, then we are back at this point: _"Pretty unclear what you want."_

Comment: @CBroe I edit qustion.
I want to get one array with unique values ​​across all iterations